# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '>' ([Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype)")

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kinesis

I am new to AWS. I want to migrate streaming data from MYSQL to Kinesis. I am trying to execute the below code but getting error. Please help me finding the errors. Thanks in advance.
ERROR: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '' ([Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype)")

### my code

```
import json
import boto3
import pymysql
from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
from pymysqlreplication.row_event import (
    DeleteRowsEvent,
    UpdateRowsEvent,
    WriteRowsEvent,
)
def main():
  kinesis = boto3.client("kinesis",region_name='ap-south-1')
  stream = BinLogStreamReader(
    connection_settings= {
      "host": "<ec2-*.compute.amazonaws.com>",
      "port": "<22>",
      "user": "<username>",
      "passwd": "<password>"},
     server_id=100,
     blocking=True,
     resume_stream=True,
    only_events=[DeleteRowsEvent, WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent])
  for binlogevent in stream:
     for row in binlogevent.rows:
      event = {"schema": binlogevent.schema,
      "table": binlogevent.table,
      "type": type(binlogevent).__name__,
      "row": row
            }       
      kinesis.put_record(StreamName="<TestStream>", Data=json.dumps(event), PartitionKey="default")
      print (json.dumps(event))
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Hi, are you meant to be connecting via port 22? Also is the database publicly accessible?

Comment: yes connecting via port 22. But the database is not publicly accessible. Also I have set the permission in IAM but still showing the error.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect over port 22? Thats the standard port for SSH

Comment: can you please tell me about that or provide any link for connecting through ssh . Actually I am new in aws

Comment: To connect to MySQL you would be using port 3306 (by default). Try that

Comment: yes I aleready tried to connect through 3306. but still same error was showing. Is there any alternate way to resolve this.